# Parse file data in makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to parse following file in makefile. I do not have scripting experience.

Input file format:

```
Disk "disk1" PORT "port1"
Disk "disk2" PORT "port2"
Disk "disk3" PORT "port3"
. . .
```

I want a list of all port numbers. I tried to parse it using foreach but no success. Could please suggest how can I parse it in Makefile?

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: What are you trying to do really?  Is the data in the `makefile`, or in a separate file?  Are you trying to create a list of the port numbers in a `make` macro?  Does the sequence of the entries matter? Could there be duplicates; would it matter?

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep:

#### Makefile

```
PORTSFILE := "DATA"
PORTS     := $(shell grep -Po "(?<=PORT \")[^\"]+" $(PORTSFILE))

test:
    @echo $(PORTS)
```

#### Example

```
$ make test
port1 port2 port3
```